# How do you get modf or modff to work properly?

Tags: objective-c, c

I am simply trying to cycle through a list of (10) names using an incrementing counter by taking the modulus of the counter with respect to the length of the list.  However, the code seems to skip a number here and there.  I have tried both modf() and modff() and different type castings, but no luck.

Here is an example of the code:

```
defaultNameList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"RacerX",@"Speed",@"Sprittle",@"Chim-Chim",@"Pops",@"Dale",@"Junior",@"Chip",@"Fred",@"Barney", nil];
```

---

```
float intpart;
int pickName = (int)(modff(entryCount/10.0,&intpart) * 10.0);
NSLog(@"%ld %f %f %f %d %@",entryCount, entryCount/10.0, modff(entryCount/10.0,&intpart), modff(entryCount/10.0,&intpart) * 10.0 ,pickName, [defaultNameList objectAtIndex:pickName]);
```

---

The console gives:

```
 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 RacerX
 1 0.100000 0.100000 1.000000 1 Speed
 2 0.200000 0.200000 2.000000 2 Sprittle
 3 0.300000 0.300000 3.000000 3 Chim-Chim
 4 0.400000 0.400000 4.000000 4 Pops
 5 0.500000 0.500000 5.000000 5 Dale
 6 0.600000 0.600000 6.000000 6 Junior
 7 0.700000 0.700000 7.000000 6 Junior
 8 0.800000 0.800000 8.000000 8 Fred
 9 0.900000 0.900000 9.000000 8 Fred
 10 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 RacerX
```

As far as I can tell it should not skip pickName = 7 or 9, but it does.

Comment: Use integer modulus. `entryCount` is already an integer, so `entryCount % 10` will yield `0`, `1`, ..., or `9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting to `(int)` truncates the file. That is, if it cannot be exactly represented in the floating-point system which is used on the actual architecture, and is a bit less than the exact value, it will be rounded towards zero. To solve this problem, round the number instead of truncating:

```
int pickName = (int)(modff(entryCount / 10.0, &intpart) * 10.0 + 0.5);
```

(This assumes that the number is not negative.)

However, since you're working with integers here, and floating-point operations are expensive, you should consider using the modulo operator instead (which operates on integers):

```
int pickName = entryCount % 10;
```

Comment: The modulo operator is the implementation I wanted and should have used, but per my understanding 9.000000 casted to int should give me 9, not 8.  Are you suggesting that although the log shows the float as 9.000000, the number is actually probably represented internally as 8.999999999....?

Comment: @DanielSaban yes, that may be the case.